# How do I read a specific selection of bytes from a file type?

Tags: c, file, file-io

I need to read a specific set of bytes from a file type for a project I'm working on.

For example, let's say we have the following open file called "image":

```
    int fd = open(image, O_RDWR, S_IRWXU);
```

Let's say I needed to read a specific section of this file starting from an offset from the beginning, say, a section starting at 1024 bytes and ending at 2048 bytes into the file.

I know we have read(),

```
    int rd = read(fd, &example, sizeof(1024));
```

and this would read into "example", the first 1024 bytes.

I know fseek exists, which would set a pointer starting where I want to start reading into "example", but only if I have a FILE type, right? I currently only have a name and it's fd,

```
    char *image;
    int fd;
```

Can I use file_name or fd in fseek? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux, 'pread()' does the trick:

```
ssize_t pread(int fd, void *buf, size_t count, off_t offset);
```

It will seek to 'offset', and then read 'count' bytes int 'buf'.

Answer (score 1):

`lseek` is the equivalent function to `fseek`, using file descriptors instead of `FILE` pointers. You can also use `pread` as Mahonri Moriancumer noted.